# Automatically print incoming email on an iPad

Tags: ipad, email, printing, automation

I'd like to automatically print all incoming email to my printer.

I don't think there's any way to do this with the native mail client, perhaps there is another app that does this?

It's definitley possible to do this with the desktop versions of Outlook or Thunderbird, I'm trying to set this up on an iPad.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Outlook is available as a free app for iPad (https://apps.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-outlook/id951937596#?platform=ipad), if it can be done with Outlook, why not use it? Or am I missing something?

Comment: And there was me thinking the idea of email was to reduce printing.

Comment: Are you planning 1 email per page or putting several on each page while reducing headers etc and printing double-sided of course.

Comment: @jaume I'm not so sure it can be setup on Outlook for iPad, I know it can be setup on desktop (PC).

Comment: @SolarMike haha, good point. It would be one email per page. The idea is to automatically print out order emails so that they can be fulfilled.

Comment: Then why not extract the relevant info to create an order list...

Answer (score 3):

Going from this comment:

> It would be one email per page. The idea is to automatically print out order emails so that they can be fulfilled.

**You're using the wrong product for your purposes.**

There are much less complex and more reliable solutions

- Printers with email addresses like [HP's ePrint](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03721293)  The printer has it's own address and you can literally email (or forward) the message to the printer
- Apple's (or any other *nix for that matter) built in mail facility.  A simple and very short batch program can be used to access and print all mail sent or fetched) from a computer.
- The full blown [Outlook client supports rules that allow you to print all incoming mail](https://www.lifewire.com/automatically-print-incoming-mail-outlook-1173140) based on criteria you set.
- Purpose built software such as [Email to Print](https://www.papercut.com/support/resources/manuals/ng-mf/applicationserver/topics/mobile-email-to-print.html#:%7E:text=Email%20to%20PrintEmail%20to%20Print%20allows%20any%20device,from%20any%20device%20that%20can%20send%20an%20email.) from Papercut will retrieve mail from a mail server and print it based on rules (like Outlook client)

Actually, the worst thing you can do is set this up on a mobile device like an iPad.  The moment it goes to sleep, all processing is done.  If the process is pushed the the background, the email to print processing stops.  If the device is dropped, it stops.

If you're taking orders to be fulfilled, you likely have a computer (or even a server) already for other purposes (accounting, internal website, etc.) that can handle this processing for you without trying to bodge something on a mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

I am quite sure that this is not possible on iPad because you always need to click "Print" if you start the printing process on iPad.
[image: iPad Printer Dialogue]

In my opinion this dialogue is obligatory.